# Performing equivalent of ArcGIS Identity_analysis (line with poly) using PostGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgis, arcpy, analysis, identity

I've got a section of arcpy code that I need to port PostGIS: [Identity_analysis](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000n000000) with the `in_features` being a line featureclass and the `identity_features` being a polygon featureclass.

I'm primarily looking for FID/LeftFID/RightFID result.

For reference, here is a screenshot of Identity_analysis result in ArcMap10.1:

[image]

PG version info:
*PostgreSQL 9.3.5, compiled by Visual C++ build 1600, 64-bit  ,  PostGIS:2.1 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1*

Comment: I don't use ArcGIS, but as far as I can see from your question and that link, you what the intersection of a line with a/some polygon(s), ie, that part of the line that is either coincident with or enclosed by a given polygon plus the ID(s) of the intersecting polygon(s)?

Comment: For this time around, I ended up going the arcpy route because I didn't have time to workout this query.  I'll post what I have so far in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gets the job done, but I have the feeling there's a better way (probably with [ST_Relate](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/ST_Relate.html)).

```
select 
    a.ogc_fid "FID_line_test"
    ,a.name "Name"
    ,lp.ogc_fid "LEFT_poly_test"
    ,rp.ogc_fid "RIGHT_poly_test"
from 
    public.line_test a 
    inner join public.poly_test lp
     on ST_Intersects( lp.wkb_geometry, ST_OffsetCurve(ST_LineMerge(a.wkb_geometry),0.001))
    inner join public.poly_test rp
     on ST_Intersects( rp.wkb_geometry, ST_OffsetCurve(ST_LineMerge(a.wkb_geometry),-0.001));
```

Results:
[image]